# Is intentional kick-down bad for the engine?

Tags: engine, gears

I have a car with automatic gear (Mitsubishi 1600cc, if it matters) and sometimes when I want to gain speed quickly (e.g. when passing a slower car in a two-way road) I do a kick-down.

I know it causes bigger fuel consumption, but I would like to know if it's also harmful to the engine itself, and if so, how?

Comment: How is "unintentional" kick-down any different?

Comment: @Krom "unintentional" kick-down happens when I don't press the accelerator enough, e.g. when driving up a sloppy road. What I mean in the question is when I press the accelerator  hard and quick, giving a "fuel boost". Maybe I am not using the correct terms?

Comment: "Kick-down" is not about a "fuel boost". You do a kick-down to let the transmission know that you want/need acceleration, and the transmission usually reacts by switching to a lower gear to allow better acceleration. And that's it. The engine is pretty much unaffected by this, except for the fact that it will have to produce more power because you put down the accelerator; that's what causes increased fuel consumption too. Accelerator down -> more fuel burned -> more power produced -> more acceleration. That's always the case, no matter if you fully kick down or just slightly press the pedal.

Comment: Your "'unintentional' kick-down" is also just the transmission switching to a lower gear and is perfectly normal operation without any extra stress on any parts.

Comment: @HannoBinder thanks, I had no idea. Isn't it worthy of an answer here?

Comment: I would agree with @HannoBinder *to a point*. Kicking down into a lower gear *is completely normal operation*. It does, however, cause more stress on an engine because the engine must run at a higher speed. With that said, it is completely within the range of what the engine/car can handle until you go past the redline ... then you are really putting the engine out there to be damaged.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 right, that's what the answer also says, as far as I can tell. Still waiting to see if there are different answers, thanks!

Comment: In fact, when driving with manual transmission you will manually change to a lower gear when you need more acceleration; and you do so when driving up a slope to keep moving forward too. That's exactly what the automatic transmission does when you kick down. The difference is only in the way you "communicate" with the transmission, and kick down is the means to let the transmission know you want it to shift down. To make it automatic and intuitive to use, the please shift down 'switch' is built into the acceleator pedal. (That'd actually be a topic for [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) :)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unless the engine speed increases excessively (in an emergency you will accept this for braking). Just about any vehicle will deny kickdown if your road speed is too high "at that time".  It will put stress on your drivetrain, but this should be well within design parameters.

For a long steep descent in a heavy or overloaded vehicle, there may be issues with richer mixtures but this will depend on the delivery method and the age/condition of the components concerned. Keeping it on or above the redline will shorten the life of the engine, timing chains may stretch, valves may "float". If you have worn valve stem seals you will suck in some oil which can foul plugs and clog exhaust components (mufflers, ceramics, catalytic converters).

But in your case, the intent is for the shift down to occur so that the engine is not "lugged" and that more power is available. It is normal, many drivers would even preempt the shift to avoid the delay and perceived "shock".